# Less than operator '<' in if statement results in 'No such file or directory'

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sh

Sure this is a simple one - still learning my way around sh scripts. I've got:-

```
if [ $3 < 480 ]; then
  blah blah command
else
   blah blah command2
fi
```

$3 is a passed variable, again an integer. However, when this script is run, it reports:-

```
line 20: 480: No such file or directory
```

Confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please use `[ "$3" -lt 480 ]` or it will be treated as input redirection inside the brackets. That's why you got the error: `480: No such file or directory`.

To review the available alternatives:

- `[ "$3" -lt 480 ]` -- numeric comparison, compatible with all POSIX shells
- `[ "$3" \< 480 ]` -- string comparison (generally wrong for numbers!), compatible with all POSIX shells
- `[[ $3 < 480 ]]` -- string comparison (generally wrong for numbers!), bash and ksh only
- `(( $3 < 480 ))` -- numeric comparison, bash and ksh only
- `(( var < 480 ))` -- numeric comparison, bash and ksh only, where `$var` is a variable containing a number

check http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions to know more information.

Comment: `\<` is wrong for numeric comparison -- it should be `-lt` that's the primary suggestion. For instance, `[ 9 \< 480 ]` is false, because `9` is a higher-order ASCII character than `4`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I just posted a correction to the answer.

Comment: @codeforester, ...so, this is a tricky thing to figure out, re: whether substantive edits that potentially conflict with author's intent should be approved (in cases where the edits *definitely* improve the answer's correctness, ie. the original author was clearly wrong). I'd have to do some reading over in meta to figure out if there's consensus on how to handle the case, or if the Right Thing is to add a newer and more-correct answer (and vote it up, and the other down).

Comment: I thought of posting my own answer.  But I think it is more beneficial to edit the accepted answer so that there is less noise on the page :)

Comment: @codeforester, ...so, I'm going to go ahead and push through your change (by adding my own, more minor, edits on top of it); if the original author objects, they can roll them back and @-notify us, at which time one of us can add our own answer separately.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use:

```
if [ $3 -lt 480 ]; then
 blah blah command
else
 blah blah command2
fi
```

Comment: Quote `"$3"` for better behavior when the value isn't actually a number (empty variable, etc). As it is, you could even have `1 -eq 1 -o`, and it would result in the test being true.

Answer (score 1):

probably in condition you need to use:

```
if [[ $3 -lt 480 ]]
```

Comment: If you're using `[[ ]]`, ie. ksh-extended syntax also available in bash, then we have available `(( $3 < 480 ))`, which is even clearer.